# Unable to find UI controls inside the page in MS Edge browser

Tags: c#, automation, microsoft-edge, ui-automation

Working on automation test SSO login for customer's app. Application opens default browser (MS Edge) with the authorization page.

I'm using MS UI Automation to find controls and act. And i'm also using "Visual UI Automation verify" (VisualUIAVerifyNative) tool to inspect the controls. The tool perfectly finds everything i need. But i can't find same elements using the code.

I am able to find Edge window and some of controls till the control named "m_webpageContent" which should contain the page itself and Ui controls inside it. But when i'm trying to find elements inside it - i'm getting null.

```
var MainWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                    new AndCondition(
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Microsoft Edge"),
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window)));

            var TheLayout = MainWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                    new AndCondition(
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "m_webpageContent"),
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Group)));

var w = TheLayout.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)); // 0 elements

w = TheLayout.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.FrameworkIdProperty, "MicrosoftEdge")); // 0 elements
```

I also tried to use TreeWalker to go through the controls tree, but it also didn't helps...

What is wrong here? 
What can i do else?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to set the debugger to check the TheLayout, make sure it is not null and contains elements. Then, you could try to use the Children scope, instead of Descendants. Also check the condition, make sure the page contains the eligible element.

Comment: Thanks, Zhi. But i already double and triple checked everything. I wrote a recursive "Tree Walker" method and logged everything it found to console, but the output doesn't contains controls that i need and that displayed in inspect tool...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
The tool i used to discover UI controls uses **UIAComWrapped.dll**. When i referenced it in my automation project, it started to find all "MicrosoftEdge" controls.